# Progressive swipe open a jquery mobile panel

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile, cordova

I have a phonegap+jquerymobile app with a panel that opens when swiping. But it happens only after the swipe, not with the swipe. I want the panel to open progressively along with the swipe like seen in Android native mobile apps (Gmail, facebook). How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I guess, what you're looking for is [Snap.js](https://github.com/jakiestfu/Snap.js/)

Simple initialization:

```
var snapper = new Snap({
  element: document.getElementById('content')
});
```

Once i've made a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TorchMan/MexXY/). Maybe it'll help you. Good luck.